# Tomcat Maven Plugin - Unable to compile Jsp Page

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, tomcat

I am a beginner in Maven build tool. In order to learn about maven I've created a simple j2ee 1.4 web-app project from the archetype in eclipse.

After that I've added the maven tomcat plugin in the pom.xml. Then I let maven to build,test,package the project. After that I set the goal to run tomcat plugin. And the tomcat plugin running successfully and showing me the link that the app is deployed on http://localhost:8080/FirstMavenApp. But whenever I'm trying to test the app on the locahost I'm getting Jsp Compilation Error -

```
SEVERE: Compilation error

org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:342)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:206)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:96)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2187)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:974)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1164)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:623)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:429)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 18, 2017 10:02:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve 
invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 


An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:

at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

However I've also tried to run the app with the configured tomcat 7 server in eclipse and it ran perfectly.But the maven tomcat plugin showing the jsp compilation error.

This is the tomcat plugin that I'm trying to use in Pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

And these are the Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.12</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

As I've told before I Haven't even created a single servlet or pojo class.There is only a simple jsp that was created by maven.But the maven tomcat plugin is unable to compile that.

So I'm pretty much lost what is going wrong here.It would be great if someone helps me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I've got a solution of the problem. And that is to change the command to start the tomcat plugin.

The right command to run tomcat 7 version 2.2 is tomcat7:run -X instead of tomcat:run

This might help someone if they face the same problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

i think issue is creating by tomcat version, upgrade the version of tomcat and also upgrade the version of other dependencies. and use jdk 8 also.

Comment: I am using jdk 8 and tomcat 7 version 2.2 maven plugin. And I didn't find any newer version rather than 2.2. But I did find a newer 3.1.0 version of servlet-api though. However I've got the solution. But thank you for the suggestion.